# Extract inner tuple and count number of items?

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to plot a histogram for the number of items in an itemset list.

The itemset list `freq_itemsets` has 1500+ elements which look somewhat like this:

> ((' Spouse', ' Min.Edu', ' United-States'), 0.12281563834034581)
>
> ((' Male',), 0.6692054912318418)
>
> ((' United-States', ' Uni.Edu'), 0.1463714259390068)

In all of these itemsets, I am only concerned with the elements of the inner container (The stuff inside the nested '()' parens). The `float` with the trailing decimals after aren't important.

What I am trying to do is extract the inner parentheses as a temporary list, store the *lengths* of each inner itemset in a list `freq_itemset_lengths`.

The end goal here is to be able to plot a histogram of the *lengths* of the itemsets found in `freq_itemsets`. Below is the code I am running:

```
freq_itemset_lengths = []

for instance in freq_itemsets:
    freq_itemset_lengths.append(len(instance))
    
print "\nHistogram for the lengths of frequent itemsets"

hist_create(freq_itemset_lengths, "Histogram of lengths of frequent itemsets", "Itemset Lengths", "Blue")
```

The method `hist_create` works fine, and is as follows:

```
def hist_create(feature, title, label, color):
    plt.hist(feature, facecolor=color, edgecolor='black')

    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(label)
    plt.ylabel("Frequency/Amount")
    plt.show()
```

The output of this is a histogram with only one bar that is plotted at `2` on the x-axis (Presumably because the itemset holds items as a tuple), and goes to 1500+ in the y-axis (Number of instances).

How do I fix this so that the histogram plots the various lengths of the itemsets themselves?

Comment: `len(instance[0])`?

Comment: @chepner Yep, as long as they're always the the first entry.

Comment: @chepner I've credited you in the acknowledgment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @chepner, you should be measuring the lengths of the innermost lists - not of the second-level list:

```
for instance in freq_itemsets:
    freq_itemset_lengths.append(len(instance[0]))
```

Alternatively,

```
for instance, _ in freq_itemsets:
    freq_itemset_lengths.append(len(instance))
```

or,

```
freq_itemset_lengths = [len(instance) for instance, _ in freq_itemsets]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    orig = [((' Spouse', ' Min.Edu', ' United-States'), 0.12281563834034581),

            ((' Male',), 0.6692054912318418),

            ((' United-States', ' Uni.Edu'), 0.1463714259390068)]

    new_list = [(x[0], len(x[0])) for x in orig ]
    print(new_list)
```

would output something like:

```
 [((' Spouse', ' Min.Edu', ' United-States'), 3), ((' Male',), 1), ((' United-States', ' Uni.Edu'), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
lst = [((' Spouse', ' Min.Edu', ' United-States'), 0.12281563834034581),
       ((' Male',), 0.6692054912318418),
       ((' United-States', ' Uni.Edu'), 0.1463714259390068)]

list(map(len, list(zip(*lst))[0]))

# [3, 1, 2]
```